# SQL request dont work as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rest

i have a PHP REST API, i did this function to get services with a certain idpro or idclient

```
 function getServices($request) {
     require_once 'db.php';
     $emp = json_decode($request->getBody());
     $id = $request->getAttribute("id");
    $sql = "select * FROM service WHERE idpro=:idpro OR idclient= :idclient ORDER BY date_debut DESC";

    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("idpro", $id);
        $stmt->bindParam("idclient", $id);
         $stmt->execute();
        $wines = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;

        return json_encode( $wines);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

I have in my database a row with `idpro=40` and `idclient=30` when i execute this function with `id=40` in get the disered result but when i execute it with `id=30` i dont get anything, i tried to execute this line in PHPMYADMIN: `select * FROM service WHERE idpro=30 OR idclient= 30`  and it worked as expected

Comment: Where are idpro and idclient variables set?

Comment: Try adding a space between the equals sign and the colon:`SELECT * FROM service WHERE idpro = :idpro OR idclient = :idclient ORDER BY date_debut DESC`

Comment: Have you looked at your "build" SQL query after you changed the values for :idpro and :idclient. The full query as you might think it looks like works fine but what is your actual query that you're building looking like? I would debug your $stmt a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "select * FROM service WHERE idpro=:idpro OR idclient=:idclient ORDER BY date_debut DESC";
```

You mentioned that it worked with idpro and it has no space between the parameter and value so try and remove the space between `idclient= :idclient` to see if thats the issue. Since it works when you execute the line I assume that its how it is syntactically called.

OR

Try using one parameter for the value. Change like this:

```
function getServices($request) {
     require_once 'db.php';
     $emp = json_decode($request->getBody());
     $id = $request->getAttribute("id");
    $sql = "select * FROM service WHERE idpro=:myID OR idclient= :myID ORDER BY date_debut DESC";

    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("myID", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $wines = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;

        return json_encode( $wines);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```